# After Adding Retrofit and OkHttp gradle tells me to configure project structure in the project structure dialog

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

After I added Retrofit and `OkHttp` I get a notification in the gradle that I have to configure project in project structure dialog what may be the issue

Below is the implementation and their versions that id added

```
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.10.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
```

Comment: Could you post a little more information with regards to the error please? Maybe copy / paste it or what you have already tried to do to resolve it?

Comment: After i add those libraries and sync gradle the notification with configure project structure in project structure appears, i was just inquiring on how to configure the project structure am new to android

Comment: It's not a error if that's what you are asking. It is an Android Studio suggestion

Comment: Thanks Poyyamozhi Ramakrishnan, so will the suggestion affect the app